# Unable to remove styling from blockquotes

Tags: css

I just got done with my first proper web design (which was for my own site) and I've styled the first line and letter of the p tags for my articles and they work just fine, but the first letter and line of blockquotes also inherit that style and I'm simply not able to change it.

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple here. For instance, look at the blockquotes [on this page](http://vhbelvadi.com/precursors-world-war-iii/).

I've tried explicitly styling the first line and letter of the blockquote but it does not seem to work. For what it's worth, I'm using first-of-type right now; I've also tried first-child but to no avail.

Update: Here's a jsfiddle --- http://bit.ly/1j70PCT

Comment: Can you put up a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anot) pseudo class to prevent the `blockquote` element from being styled in the initial declaration:

```
.entry-content :not(blockquote) p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

..or overwrite the styling with a more specific selector:

```
.entry-content blockquote p:first-of-type:first-letter {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Josh Crozier. :not() works like a charm. I haven't tried the other answers, but I've updated the jsfiddle with the working code as well, just in case.

Comment: Lost my edit window: Of all the options mentioned here, I think this one is most convenient because the blockquote p tags are already inheriting styling and using this pseudo element means I do not have to define blockquotes again, explicitly. (Especially since I want them to inherit the p styling — it's a different issue if you don't, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

```
blockquote > p:first-letter {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation.